# jQuery: cloning table row adds row within last row instead of below

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, clone

I am using the following lines to clone the last row of a table and add it below that one.

The cloning works as intended and also the fields and values are updated correctly. 
The only issue I have is that the row seems to get inserted within the last row instead of below it. 
I am using Bootstrap 3 for the styling, just in case.
Also, the table and button only get added after making certain selections on the site.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnAdd', function() {
    var tableID = $('.outputTable').attr('id');
    var tempID = 9000000;
    var rowCount = $('#'+tableID+' >tbody >tr').length + 1;
    var trOld = $('#'+tableID).find('tbody tr:last');
    var trNew = trOld.clone();
    $('#'+tableID+' >tbody').after(trNew);
    trNew.attr('id', tempID);
    trNew.find('.sortID').text(rowCount);
    tempID++;
    console.log(tempID);
});
```

Many thanks for any advice, Tim.

Comment: Is it your trOld var? Should it be tbody tr:last-child?

Comment: No, dont think so - that was working for me on other tables before.

Comment: I did'nt think "last" was a selector, thought it was "last-child" or "last-of-type"

Comment: insert a row ***after*** the `tbody`? well looks like you can just use `appendTo` to append the new row to the `tbody` instead. try `trNew.appendTo('#'+tableID+' >tbody')` instead of `$('#'+tableID+' >tbody').after(trNew);`

Comment: Awesome - thanks a lot, King King ! That fixed it. Wanna post this as an answer ? Then I can close the post. Feel free to add any other suggestions if you have. :)